# random.SystemRandom().choice() vs random.choice()

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between `random.SystemRandom().choice()` & `random.choice()` in python?

I have [seen the former being used](https://programtalk.com/python-examples/random.SystemRandom.choice/), in more than one place. But its not mention [py2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) or [py3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.choice) documentation.

Comment: It is mentioned. You probably just weren't looking in the [right place](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom). It's OS dependent and thus is not available on all systems.

Answer (score 9):

[`random.SystemRandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.SystemRandom) is a random number generator class intended for cryptographic use. It uses [`os.urandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) for its underlying byte stream; `os.urandom` pulls from an OS-dependent cryptographic random number source, sometimes [`/dev/urandom`](https://linux.die.net/man/4/urandom) (but not always, even when `/dev/urandom` exists.

The `SystemRandom` class provides all random number generation methods the `random` module itself does, with the same meanings, just using a cryptographic RNG to implement them. `random.choice` and the `choice` method of a `SystemRandom` instance both make a random choice from an input sequence, but only `SystemRandom` is suitable for cryptographic use. `random.choice`'s choices can be predicted by an adversary without much difficulty.

Comment: Please correct me if I understood it wrong.
So, if you are generating random char/numbers for password or anything with a security implication, best to use random.SystemRandom().choice().    

That being said, `os.urandom` is from python but `OS-dependent cryptographic random number source`, what does that mean. Is it different between mac, linux & windows? What if the next version of any of the OS doesn't support it? Or one of the distros of Linux removes it for improving efficiency. Does this have to be a try exception block?

Comment: Also, where in the documentation does it say that [random.SystemRandom().choice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=systemrandom#random.SystemRandom) is possible?

I am trying to "learn to read" the documentation properly. Did the doc miss it or did I miss understand it?

Comment: @user7579349: The documentation kind of sucks in this spot. The fact that `random.SystemRandom` has a `choice` method is just sort of vaguely implied by the combination of an earlier line ("The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the random.Random class.") and the never-explicitly-stated fact that `random.SystemRandom` provides the same API as `random.Random` (except for seed and state manipulation).

Comment: I believe `os.urandom` is available on all common OSes now, and it would be incredibly unlikely for it to be removed. Too much depends on OS cryptographic random number sources.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other support document I can look up to find the info when documentation falls short?

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation for `random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) it returns a random element from a sequence provided as a parameter to the function. If the sequence does not exist, it returns an error. The proper function call is

```py
random.choice(someSequence)
```

From the same page, you can see that the [random.SystemRandom()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#alternative-generator) is just an alternative generator that generates random number from the operating system resources and is not available on all systems.

Comment: This answer misses the purpose of `SystemRandom`, which is to be suitable for cryptographic use.

Comment: I'm new to python so I missed that entirely. I guess what they say is true: `The fastest way to get the answer to a question is to post the wrong answer on the internet.`